# viewsets not working with ^ and $ added and invalid literal for int() with base 10: on string regex django rest framework

Tags: python, regex, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have the following urls which are directed towards `viewsets` in `djangorestframework`

```
router.register(r'city-list', CityListViewSet, base_name='city-list')
```

as is above this url works but if I do this:

```
router.register(r'^city-list$', CityListViewSet, base_name='city-list')
```

it breaks and I get a **404 error**. the `^` is a regex expression for pattern matching from the beginning, the `$` is like the `^` but for pattern matching in the back.

As well, check out this url:

```
router.register(r'venue-filter-options-list/(?P<city>[a-zA-Z]+)'
```

Having the same problem with `^` and `$` I am getting an error when I input a string into the `city` placeholder

if I put for example `chicago` into the `city` placeholder when calling the url in the browser

I get the following error in the django debug page:

> Exception Type:   ValueError
>
> Exception Value:
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'chicago'

that doesn't make any sense my regex is correct.

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: can you put the code where you put chicago in the placeholder ?

Comment: Could you show your viewset?

Comment: If you only need to change your `lookup_field` then simply add `lookup_field = "your_field_name"` in your viewset. You don't need to write your own regex. Viewsets are meant to take care of those implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Viewsets are Class based and you'd need to call `.as_view()` in the url.
2. You should specify methods as a dict to `as_view()`
3. ViewSet get expects `pk` field to query by default, So if you want to use something else, you need to change the lookup field in the ViewSet declaration. The error is telling you that an int value **the pk** is required not a string.
   Read more from the doc http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/